# How can I make a C pointer wait if called from a different thread, but work in a callback?

Tags: rust, ffi, mruby

I'm trying to implement a thread-safe version of an [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby) Rust binding.

mruby has a `*mut MRState` (a wrapper over `mrb_state`). You need to pass this `*mut MRState` when running mruby code. The mruby code has a Rust callback that it can call where it passes the same `*mut MRState` variable.

This `*mut MRState` is wrapped in a `MRuby` `struct` which I'm trying to make thread-safe. The problem is that if I wrap `MRuby` in a `Mutex`, it won't be able to re-enter inside of the Rust-written callback.

I'm currently wrapping `MRuby` in a `RwLock` but it's not very useful. The `*mut MRState` should be in a more permissive lock that lets it run inside of the callbacks.

How can I make `MRuby` work in both the callback and be forced to wait if called from different threads?

Apart from this, I'm having an issue with the `*mut MRState` inside `MRuby` which is not `Send` & `Sync`.

```
struct MRuby {
    mrb: *mut MRState,
    ...
}
```

This is an example of the callback.

```
// this callback will be run with a mrb_ function with takes
// *mut MRState as an argument, so it would need to lock
extern "C" callback(...) {
    // I need to use MRuby here which will make use of
    // its inner *mut MRState
    ...
}
```

This is an example of running mruby on a thread. `mruby` variable here could be an `Arc<RwLock<MRuby>>`.

```
thread::spawn(move || {
    mruby.run("*mruby code*"); // should run sequentially with
                               // with a lock on *mut MRState
});
```

The main reason why I want to implement this is not functionality. Actually, it's [`catch_panic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.catch_panic.html) which I need in order to catch any possible panics from the Rust callback. `catch_panic` runs in another thread, so I need to make `MRuby` thread-safe. Rust will stabilize [`std::panic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/index.html) only in 1.9.0 and until then I would need a working solution that doesn't need Rust nightly.

CORRECTION

Due to a bug in Rust's documentation generation, `catch_panic` is only marked as deprecated and not as unstable, even though it is. So a very simple solution is to just use `std::panic` and give up on thread-safety. I'm going to leave the question open, though, in case there is a good answer to this, even though my personal interest is lower now considering the aforementioned.

Comment: It rather sounds like you want a [reentrant lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) of some kind.

Comment: Sure, but [`ReentrantMutex`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/sys/common/remutex.rs#L24) is not even in `std`. :D